# How can I create in Stata a time variable for the X axis with 1920 as year(0)?

Tags: stata

Time relative to Suffrage law

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAgeD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what your data look like, but my guess is

```
gen myyear = year - 1920
```

Comment: Nick, thank you for your reply! What I am trying to recreate are the figures two and four from the paper: WOMEN’S SUFFRAGE, POLITICAL RESPONSIVENESS, AND CHILD SURVIVAL IN AMERICAN HISTORY, by Grant Miller. (I new to this site, and  I am not allowed to post images yet). Can you suggest what codes to use for the figures? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are asking people to find and read a paper, imagine your data and then imagine code for you. Sorry, but no from me. (In any case, is my answer right or wrong, because I do think it answers the question on the information you gave?)